# Dynamic topic name configuration for spring kafka when using spring integration Kafka adapters?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-kafka

I have spring integration flows which i need to reuse again.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow sendToKafkaFlowRequest(@Value("${kafka.document-consume-topic}") String topic,
                                              ProducerFactory<?, Message> producerFactory) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("kafkaRequestChannel")
            .handle(Kafka
                    .outboundChannelAdapter(producerFactory)
                    .messageKey(m -> m
                            .getHeaders()
                            .get(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.SEQUENCE_NUMBER))
                    .topicExpression("headers[kafka_topic] ?: '" + topic + "'"))
            .get();
}


@Bean
public IntegrationFlow listeningFromKafkaFlow(@Value("${kafka.document-consume-topic}") String topic,
                                              ConsumerFactory<?, Message> consumerFactory) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Kafka.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(consumerFactory, ListenerMode.record, topic)
            .configureListenerContainer(c -> c.ackMode(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode.RECORD))
            .retryTemplate(new RetryTemplate())
            .filterInRetry(true))
            .channel("interMessageChannel")
            .get();
}
```

I wanted to reuse these two flows again and again for multiple topics. But the problem is topic is hardcoded.
The question is can we use headers of the message to place topic name inside it ? Will this be a problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Look, `Kafka.messageDrivenChannelAdapter()` can accept several topics and you'll need only one flow on the matter, therefore.

Right, you always can set `kafka_topic` header into the message before sending to Kafka via `Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter()`. And again: you don't need to duplicate `IntegrationFlow` here as well. The only one to send to the topic resolved against message is fully sufficient.

Comment: What about the listeningFromKafkaFlow(), How not to duplicate it how i can consume message without duplicating the same flow ?

Comment: I told you: the `Kafka.messageDrivenChannelAdapter()` can accept vararg for topics. You can't just inject all your topics into the `listeningFromKafkaFlow` bean definition and delegate them to the `Kafka.messageDrivenChannelAdapter()`